# JavaScript Regex capture and replace for optional parts

Tags: javascript, regex

I am finding hard time to perform `Capture and Replace` for following lines with `Regex` in `JavaScript`:

```
// Lines:
This is <span>foo</span>.
This is <span>(Capital) foo</span>.
This is <span>foo (Plural)</span>.
This is <span>(Capital) foo (Plural)</span>.
```

I need `This is foo.` for all of the above.

I tried as:

```
var pattern = /<span>(\(Capital\))?\s?(\w+)\s?(\(Plural\))?<\/span>/;

var text1 = "This is <span>foo</span>";
var text2 = "This is <span>(Capital) foo</span>";
var text3 = "This is <span>foo (Plural)</span>";
var text4 = "This is <span>(Capital) foo (Plural)</span>";

text1.replace(pattern, function(_, m){ return m; });
text2.replace(pattern, function(_, m){ return m; });
text3.replace(pattern, function(_, m){ return m; });
text4.replace(pattern, function(_, m){ return m; });
```

But its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the below regex ,

```
<span>(?:\(Capital\))?\s*(\w+)\s*(?:\(Plural\))?<\/span>
```

Replace the matched characters with the chars in group index 1.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vY0gH6/1)

```
> "This is <span>foo</span>.".replace(/<span>(?:\(Capital\))?\s*(\w+)\s*(?:\(Plural\))?<\/span>/g, '$1');
'This is foo.'
> "This is <span>(Capital) foo</span>.".replace(/<span>(?:\(Capital\))?\s*(\w+)\s*(?:\(Plural\))?<\/span>/g, '$1');
'This is foo.'
> "This is <span>foo (Plural)</span>.".replace(/<span>(?:\(Capital\))?\s*(\w+)\s*(?:\(Plural\))?<\/span>/g, '$1');
'This is foo.'
> "This is <span>(Capital) foo (Plural)</span>.".replace(/<span>(?:\(Capital\))?\s*(\w+)\s*(?:\(Plural\))?<\/span>/g, '$1');
'This is foo.'
```

Comment: Looks like I was also close :). Thanks anyway. Great help.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't matter what is in between the `<>` or `()` then:

```
text.replace(/[<(][^>)]+[>)]/g, '').replace(/ {2,}/g, ' ');
```

(Added the 2nd replace, makes sure there's no double spaces left behind)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your regex to this:

```
var r = str.replace(/(?:</?span>| *\((?:Capital|Plural)\)) */gmi, "");
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vK1yA8/1)

Comment: This looks closer to what I am expecting. Could you explain a little bit for the pattern used? That would be quite helpful.

Comment: Yes sure do check the linked demo and it has great explanation of regex on RHS. Here `</?span>` matches `<span>` or `</span>` and then `\((?:Capital|Plural)\)` matches both `(Capital)` OR `(Plural)`.